# Position of Divs , no spaces, *whit photo

Tags: css

i have the problem whit my layout, make in css some, whit no javascript because i dont know dynamically position my divs(posts)...this divs have spaces, make lines and i dont want lines because are diferent sizes, see the photo to understand perfectly:

see this photo please

http://postimage.org/image/hibb48iq3/

this is the normal, but the next see this:

http://postimage.org/image/6h9b8mpt9/

this big space i dont want, im try use various properties of display in the css but nothing change this big space, my css to this is it:

```
#post {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
    background: #fbffff;
    color: #6d6d6d;
    margin:10px 0;
    padding:15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: tahoma;
    line-height: 20px;
    width:30%;
    float:right;

}
```

if someone have some solution, or using css or javascript of a made dinamyc, my code is in ruby on rails some to inform.

Im thanks and wait response, please.

Comment: I see the big space. So do you want to move the box below the big space where the big space is? Please create the page with html and css on jsfiddle.net, save it and include the link to your jsfiddle in your answer. Then i can try to help you effectively.

Comment: Its here the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DLKP6/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your going for a "Pinterest" layout. Your best bet is to use jQuery and add the plugin [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) or [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Sorry but this type of plugin dont help me, i test but i want make my own aplicattion.

Comment: you are asking the same question again, and what do you mean by **i want make my own aplicattion**, if you want to then make it first and then come up with the question